# Finding the first and last days of each month in the period of time

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have a task to make website article stats based on database results. I need to calculate the amount of articles was added monthly and pass these results to JavaScript stats function.

The first what I'm doing is finding the entire period in which articles have been added:

```
SELECT MIN(date) as startdate FROM articles LIMIT 1 

SELECT MAX(date) as enddate FROM articles LIMIT 1
```

Now I have the period which starts with `$startDate` and ends with `$endDate`. These variables are unix timestamps as they are in the database. The column `date` in database is also unix timestamp.

Next, I should find the amount of articles have been added in each month doing a query in foreach loop like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM articles 
    WHERE date > ".$startMonth." AND date < ".$endMonth
```

But to make that I need to find the first and the last days of each month in the period. And I stucked at this moment. So please can you please suggest me how to find these first and last days as array. I think I should make something like `strtotime("+1 month",$date)` in a while loop until `$startDate` equals `$endDate`. Thanks in advance.

**Upd.** There are total 46 articles in the database. What I am willing to have are results grouped by month:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(id) as total FROM `articles`
  WHERE `author`=$author
     GROUP BY date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
```

results:
   month   posts
   11-2010 13
   12-2010 33

Comment: please use exactly this : `SELECT date_format(date, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(*) as total FROM articles GROUP BY 1;`

Comment: Maybe this is the format required? `SELECT date_format(date, '%M %Y'), COUNT(*) as total FROM articles GROUP BY 1;`

Comment: the select column is wrong, use this `SELECT date_format(date, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(*) as total FROM articles GROUP BY 1;` OR `SELECT date_format(date, '%m-%Y'), COUNT(*) as total FROM articles GROUP BY 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can achieve this using a `GROUP BY`, like

```
SELECT date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(id) as total 
FROM articles 
GROUP BY date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m');
```

And you do not need the date boundaries ...

Comment: or you could simple use `GROUP BY 1`

Comment: Thanks, however it selects the amount of all articles as the first month despite the fact I am fetching results in the while loop and there are articles added in november and december.

Comment: @ajreal - So if I use GROUP By and while loop I only get one result? How do I get multiple results grouped?

Comment: @laurencepeter5 - the GROUP BY will group posts for every month, so you just need to loop thru the results for each month

Comment: @ajreal it returns only one row :(

Comment: @laurencepeter5 - Can you update your question with the full query? I would think you only has posts for current month

Comment: @ajreal There are for now 13 posts in november and 33 in december. Fetching your query in a while loop somehow returns the only result: total amount 46 posts by 30.11.2010. Does it group only finished months (today is 20th  of december) ?

Comment: @laurencepeter5 - I guess your misunderstanding the usage, the group by should return '2010-11, 2010-12...`, please update your question with full query